# Makefile start and end of target

Tags: makefile

Hello I have some debug target in my makefile.

How I can control what code will be inside this target?

I don't want to something after echo will be in target test, but now it is.

```
.PHONY: test
test:
    @echo ${TYPE}




ifndef SOME
    SOME=some123
endif
```

```
$ make test
typevalue
SOME=some123
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* I understand what you're asking.

A makefile rule lasts from the introduction of the target, up until the next line which is not part of a recipe.  Blank lines, comment lines, and preprocessor lines like `ifeq` do not count as ending a recipe.

Other lines that begin with TAB characters are part of the recipe.  Lines that don't begin with a TAB will end the recipe.

So, in your makefile above simply ensure that the assignment `SOME=some123` does not start with a TAB character.